# Ruby uninitialized constant name error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nameerror

I have this strange error I don't understand. I have a model `User` defined as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :name, :email

has_many :caves
end
```

And an associated model `Cave` defined as:

```
class Cave < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

On my user's show method, I offer to create a new cave:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.caves.build]) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

But when I display the page, I get the following error:

```
NameError in Users#show
Showing E:/Vinisync/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #19 raised:

uninitialized constant User::Cafe

Extracted source (around line #19):
16: </p>
17: 
18: <h2>Add a Cave</h2>
19: <%= form_for([@user, @user.caves.build]) do |f| %>
20:   <div class="field">
21:     <%= f.label :name %><br />
22:     <%= f.text_field :name %>
```

I don't know where the hell this 'Cafe' comes from, I don't have this word anywhere in my code!
What I've noticed is that if I rename the associated in User.rb has `has_many :cave` instead of `has_many :caves` as currently (and change it in the form in the users's show.html.erb, the page displays normally. But my relationshiop is one to many, so it should read as 'caves' in User, not 'cave'. I believe I've read all related questions here on SO and elsewhere, but I none of the solutions seem to apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like Rails doesn't realize that the singular of Caves is Cave. You can set this up manually in config/initializers/inflections.rb:

```
inflect.irregular 'cave', 'caves'
```

Then it will try to find Cave instead of Cafe.

Comment: Thanks, that does it! You can't know how much I am relieved to have gotten rid of this, it's been driving me crazy fo days! Is that frequent to have this kind of errors?

Comment: Usually Rails is pretty good about inflections and finding the correct pluralized or singularized word... Words with "v" in them seem to mess it up more often than usual though. For example, the default singular of "loves" is "lofe."

Comment: Exactly the same error as I had then. I'm new to ruby, I'll keep an eye on this then, especially since I intend my models to be partly in french.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Ruby uses the somewhat "inventive" [Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) to singularize your "Caves" and ends up generating "Cafe".

You can fix the behavior in inflections.rb in your config.

Answer (score -1):

The error points you to your `show.html.erb` view file, not to your `new.html.erb` view file.

maybe you have a typo on the `show.html.erb`. Check it!